# MaaS - cloud-init Connection failed talking to archive.ubuntu.com

Tags: maas

Am new to MaaS but have configured a MaaS 2.4.2 setup consisting of the following:

1. VM running Ubuntu 18.04 acting as MaaS Master and MaaS controller.

   - dual vNICs;

     - both on the same physical network, but one with
     - one vNIC configured with a static IP address on my main network (10.0.0.180)
     - one vNIC configured with a static IP address on my MaaS node network (172.24.124.1)
   - MaaS controller is configured to do DHCP with a range on the MaaS node network
2. As a test node, I have a DL360 on the same physical network

I have successfully got the DL360 to PXE boot, load the Ubuntu image, enlist and shutdown ready for commissioning.

However, during the enlisting process, I saw the following errors:

```
cloud-init[1310]: Err: 1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
[ 199.153101] cloud-init[1310]:  Connection failed [IP: 172.24.124.1 8000]
```

This times out after 60 seconds, then we see two more similar requests timing out.  Subsequent requests succeed and the node then completes enlisting and appears in the MaaS console.  Commissioning fails however - although the node autopowers on and PXE boots, I get the same three failed http requests and then a report of commissioning fail (missing dependencies) for the install-lldpd stages

I know that the node can talk back to the MaaS controller as the download of the Ubuntu image worked successfully, however, there seems to be a problem with the maas-proxy.

I've tested the proxy locally from the MaaS controller via curl and it can download content from the internet fine.

Any ideas on how to diagnose this or what's going wrong?  I understand there's no easy way to log into the node during the commissioning stage to debug further?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was an ipv6 DNS problem; disabling IPv6 solved both problems by following these instructions https://support.purevpn.com/how-to-disable-ipv6-linuxubuntu